# Referencing Two dll's with same simple name

Tags: vb.net, solidworks

I'm working on a Solidworks Addin using VB.NET that utilizes the Solidworks API and CAMWorks API.

Basically, Solidworks has integrated a free version of CAMWorks dubbed "SolidworksCAM". The API dll reference for CAMWorks and SolidworksCAM are different, each with a unique GUID, but maintaining the same simple name of "Interop.CAMWorksLib.dll". The API functions are 100% the same, just each software ships with a different GUID for their API. This GUID ties back to the COM assembly loaded in Solidworks, so if Solidworks has SolidworksCAM loaded and my addin is complied with the CAMWorks API reference it will fail to retrieve the COM object.

How can I achieve compatibility between these two APIs without having two projects? Is it even possible? Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably need to manually create the interop DLL using [Tlbimp.exe with the /namespace parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer).  Once you've created a different interop for each, using a different namespace for each one, then you need to have your .NET project just reference those two DLLs directly as a .NET library file reference rather than as a COM reference.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I post a question to a board it seems like I always solve it soon after.

<strike>For future reference, I used Reflection to dynamically load the Dlls. Below is some more detailed information.</strike>

I put the Dlls in two different folders in my project and set them to Copy. I then used [Assembly.LoadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2) to load the dll and get its assembly. I used this assembly to get the constructor class "CWAppClass" and fed its type into [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get an instance of the main CWApp class. This way you can use whichever one doesn't error. Thanks for the help!

After taking advice to not use LoadFile(), i have found that there is a method in the Solidworks API that allows you to do this. By using [Sldworks::GetAddInObject](http://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks~solidworks.interop.sldworks.isldworks~getaddinobject.html?verRedirect=1) you can get the addin object for whichever addin you choose. Then you can use the CAMWORKSADDINLib to interact with this. Thanks for the suggestion, this it the perfect solution for my problem.

Comment: Google "coding horror rubber ducky" to learn more.  Steven gave you good advice, never use LoadFile().